# Payment Captured, No order processed in Magento

Tags: orders, backend, payment, authorize.net, order-state

New Magento 2 Install. 
Authorize.net and Paypal having the same issue.

1. Order is placed on our website
2. Payment is captured and accepted
3. The order DOES NOT show up in Magento`s backend.
4. Customer does not receive any confirmation emails

Making big problems at the moment.  I tested it myself, and after it processed the credit card, I had a brief error that said, "Unique Constraint Violation Found"

Not even sure where to look for this, there's no real supported threads answering this question, can anyone offer guidance?

-Justin