# Payment processes, but order doesn't show up in backend?

Tags: orders, checkout, payment

When somebody checks out on our store (options are Paypal or Credit Card) they get a receipt from the gateway and a more detailed invoice from Magento. We're copied on both.

About a month ago, in the midst of some other perfectly normal orders, we got a PayPal receipt for an order that didn't appear in Magento. We assumed this was a clever con, but after logging into Paypal, the transaction was in there - and the receipt included the line items, passed over from Magento. It just didn't exist anywhere in the Magento backend.

This seemed odd but it only happened once, so we moved on with our lives and adjusted the stock levels manually.

Today, the same thing has happened - but this time the customer has checked out using CC, and the merchant gateway receipt doesn't include the order line items. We can see the receipt mailed out to the customer from our gateway, we can see the money in our account, but there's no trace of it in Magento - which means we don't know what they actually bought.

We can just email them and ask, but it's a pretty bad look. Any guesses what's happening here? Have you ever witnessed similar behaviour, or is there something I can do to debug?

This time tomorrow I'll be able to check if it has tracked into Google Analytics, which will tell me if the customer made it to the "order confirmed" screen on our site. When it was just Paypal I thought maybe they hadn't returned to the site (although I think Magento creates the order when you hit submit, not after you return from Paypal). The CC gateway is integrated into the checkout flow, so they would never have even left the site.

This question has been asked before [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/33265/captured-payment-but-order-doesnt-show-up-in-backend) by someone else but was closed as off topic. The issue isn't reliably reproducible, but I still think it'd be useful to future readers to discuss what might cause this - even if we can't nail down the exact cause. And I'm certain that (unless I change something) it will happen again.

Appreciate any tips!

In my case (upgrading to 2.1.0 from 2.0.7), a column was missing from the sales_invoice_grid table.  I tracked it down by looking at the system.log in [magentoRootDirector]/var/log.  The following message was logged there (with a very long query after it); Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'base_grand_total' in 'field list'.  I was able to track the table down that was missing the column by copying the query and trying to run it in MySql Workbench.  It also popped up when clicking on sales/invoices in the admin console.  The following message was shown there; Notice: Undefined index: base_grand_total in /var/www/public/vendor/magento/module-sales/Ui/Component/Listing/Column/Price.php on line 55.  After adding the column in sales_invoice_grid, orders are now processing correctly.  There is now the issue that magento is trying to retrieve the IPN from paypal but erroring out because the order doesn't exist, but that isn't hindering new orders.

Comment: This isn't something we can help you solve without looking at your installation. I would start off by looking at the order grid table and see if it's just missing there. It's *possible* the order is just missing in the grid so you can't search for it in the admin. From there, you'll need to look at your customization related to orders.

Comment: There was an error in a third  party extension was causing a PHP Fatal error: Call to undefined method Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type_Simple::getUsedProducts() in .. /app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Product/Type/Configurable/Attribute/Collection.php on line 160   Magento crashes and the order is not created. But payment was made.

Comment: This is probably caused by a Fatal Error of an 3rd party observer. Enable ini_set('display_errors', 1) and Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true); in your index.php right before you place the order. If thats the issue it will show up on the screen. In my case it was: Fatal error: Call to a member function getProductType() on a non-object in a Giftvoucher extension.